# custom meta in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

im fetching a post on a separate page
its all working expect the custom value meta.

```
<?php 
$the_id =   "";
if(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'newpostid', 'true')) {
$the_id =     get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'newpostid', 'true'); 
 }else if(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'oldpostid', 'true')) {
$the_id =     get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'oldpostid', 'true').''; } ?>


<?php
$post_id = $the_id;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id); ?>

<h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
```

Can anyone help me get a custom field value?

This what I got:

```
<?php echo $queried_post->get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'newpostid', 'true'); ?>
```

But its causing fatal error

Pleas help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_post_meta is just a function, not a method of $queried_post.

You can use such costruction:

```
get_post_meta($queried_post->ID, 'newpostid', 'true');
```

but it will be same to:

```
get_post_meta($post_id, 'newpostid', 'true');
```

or

```
get_post_meta($the_id, 'newpostid', 'true');
```